# Do I need Retrofit Scalers Converter?

Tags: android, retrofit2

I see online some people use `ScalerConverterFactory.create()` to deserialize Strings and other primitive types. Is this necessary or can `Moshi` and `kotlinx` serialization handle these primitive types?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether you're using JSON. If your response body is unquoted, use the Scalar converter:

```
Hello I'm plain text
```

If it's quoted, use a JSON converter.

```
"Hello, I'm a JSON string"
```

Comment: Would it make sense to use both if your api also returned JSON and unquoted text? Would they block each other?

Comment: They would be mutually ambiguous, unless you used Any as the return type / request type for the JSON one. It needs to be installed last.